# python 3 pandas convert string time into yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Imagine i have the following timestamps in a dataframe called df

```
           time
1          2019-05-03 15:26:37.000
2          2019-05-10 19:26:29.000
3          2019-05-10 23:39:07.000
4          2019-05-08 13:52:08.000
```

I am planning to convert it into

```
           time
1          2019-05-03
2          2019-05-10
3          2019-05-10
4          2019-05-08
```

so that I can do a group by to count how many date points per day

```
df2=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d-%b-%y')
```

returns the following errors

```
ValueError: time data '2019-05-04 14:08:33.000' does not match format '%d-%b-%y' (match)

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

If I do:

```
request_time_date_df2=pd.to_datetime(ride_df['requested_time'], unit='D')
```

return

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-05-04 14:08:33.000'
```

If I do

```
df2=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d-%b-%y', errors='ignore')
```

return the same

```
           time
1          2019-05-03 15:26:37.000
2          2019-05-10 19:26:29.000
3          2019-05-10 23:39:07.000
4          2019-05-08 13:52:08.000
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other possible solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2019-05-03 15:26:37.000', '2019-05-10 19:26:29.000', '2019-05-10 23:39:07.000', '2019-05-08 13:52:08.000']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         time
0  2019-05-03
1  2019-05-10
2  2019-05-10
3  2019-05-08
```

NOTE: If you want to group by day, you don't need to format days beforehand, just convert it to datetime and look at [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) (with frequency set to `'D'`).

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2019-05-03 15:26:37.000', '2019-05-10 19:26:29.000', '2019-05-10 23:39:07.000', '2019-05-08 13:52:08.000'],
                   'data':[1, 1, 1, 1]})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='D'))['data'].sum())
```

Prints:

```
time
2019-05-03    1
2019-05-04    0
2019-05-05    0
2019-05-06    0
2019-05-07    0
2019-05-08    1
2019-05-09    0
2019-05-10    2
Freq: D, Name: data, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! both solutions work great! Learning a lot!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could use:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.normalize() # if series is a object dtype
```

Or:

```
df['time'].dt.normalize() #if series is a datetime dtype
```

---

```
1   2019-05-03
2   2019-05-10
3   2019-05-10
4   2019-05-08
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you! both solutions work great! Learning a lot!